# Ubuntu 16.04 Lenovo Y520 freezes on shutdown/restart

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, lenovo, freeze

I have a Lenovo Y520 with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 installed. 
When I try to shutdown Ubuntu, or restart, it freezes the screen and nothing happens.

I tried updating and using fix with changing in /etc/default/grub,

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
```

Then updating `grub`, but nothing seems to work.

I'm new to Linux and I just started learning terminal, so I would really appreciate a guide through potential fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - maybe it will help you

Working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

1. Open: `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
2. Find: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
3. Add: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force apm=power_off"`
4. Open: `sudo nano /etc/modules`
5. Add: `apm power_off=1`
6. Update grub: `sudo update-grub`
7. Install Nvidia 930 and update
8. Restart your pc: `sudo shutdown -r now`